# Do I need to make a migration if I change null and blank values on a Model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Booking(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('Session'), to=Session, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Quantity'), default=1, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=_('Price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
                                default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=100, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('Email'), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Phone Number'), max_length=30, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Say I need to change my email and phone_number fields. I want them to have `null=False` and `blank=False`. Do these alterations require a new migration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they do. `null=False` requires a change to the database schema itself; `blank=False` does not, but Django needs a migration anyway so that the migration runner's internal graph of the model state is up to date.

Comment: If I'm changing blank to True after adding some data is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Sure. To check it you can run `python manage.py makemigrations --dry-run` (the --dry-run doesn't save a new migration file, but shows if it's necessary)

Comment: I had no idea about that command option, thank you so much! It will be quite useful

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#field-options

Django document says:

> null
>
> If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default >is False.
>
> blank
>
> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, 
>   whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form 
>   validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, 
>   the field will be required.

For change in `null` you need to migrate

For change in `blank` you need not to migrate, because its admin form related

Answer (score 1):

Sure they do. Every change you made to your model fields (from simply altering the `help_text` to completely rename a model field) requires to `makemigrations` and `migrate` in order to reconstruct your model in the future.